# Dynamic memory allocation trouble

Tags: c

The program stops running after memory is allocated to "namn". Why?
The goal is to enter two SEPARATE strings and concatenate them, then print.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char namn, fornamn[25], efternamn[25];
    scanf("%s", fornamn);
    scanf("%s", efternamn);

    namn = malloc((strlen(fornamn)+strlen(efternamn)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(namn, fornamn);
    strcat(namn, efternamn);
    printf("%s", namn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char namn` => `char *namn`. The warnings of your compiler should probably have helped you.

Comment: The way you prevent this from happening is the **enable compiler warnings** and do not accept code until it compiles -- without warning. For gcc add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your compile string. For clang, add `-Weverything`, for VS (`cl.exe`) add `/W3` (or `/W4` for truly everything)

Comment: Wow... Should've noticed that. Thank you.

Comment: Also, `sizeof(char)` is *defined* to be one.

Answer (score 2):

Since `namn` is of type `char`, the return value of `malloc` is truncated to the size of a char, which is insufficient to store a valid pointer value.

Fix is:

```
char *namn;
```

Your compiler probably issues a lot of warnings when compiling. It's always interesting to read them. Example with `gcc` (without options: default warning setting):

```
L:\>gcc test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:11:6: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 namn = malloc((strlen(fornamn)+strlen(efternamn)+1)*sizeof(char));
      ^
```

Aside, you can limit user input and avoid buffer overflow with:

```
scanf("%24s", fornamn);
scanf("%24s", efternamn);
```

And `sizeof(char)` is always 1. So no need to specify it when allocating string memory.

Answer (score 0):

The variable namn is a simple char. Malloc returns a pointer to the memory. Hence, you need a char pointer (char *namn).